# Hibernate Flush Mode

Tags: hibernate

```
 Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setFirstName("Java");
            person.setLastName("Hibernate");
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(person);
            BigInteger count = (BigInteger) session.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from Person")
                    .setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL).getSingleResult();
            System.out.println("Total records are= " + count);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
```

Hibernate Configuration File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_practice</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">*****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="connection.autocommit">false</property>
        <mapping class="entities.Person"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am using hibernate flush mode as MANUAL. But save method is executing insert method though I am not calling session.flush() method. I am using hibernate 5.2.12 and mysql dirver 8.0.6

```
Output is below:
 Hibernate: 
   insert into  person (first_name, last_name) values (?, ?) 
 Hibernate: 
   select count(*) from Person 
 Total records are= 5
```

HibenateUtil class is below:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
  private static StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry;
  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  static{
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
          try {
            standardServiceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
            MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources(standardServiceRegistry);
            Metadata metadata = metadataSources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
            sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (standardServiceRegistry != null) {
              StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(standardServiceRegistry);
            }
          }
        }
  }
  //Utility method to return SessionFactory
  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
      return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

HibernateUtil Class is below Please help me.

Comment: Could you please show your `hibernate.cfg.xml`? And as I understand `HibernateUtil` is your custom class. Could you please show the `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory()` implementation.

Comment: Hi Stem I have added configuration file and HibernateUtil Class. Please help me to solve my query.

Comment: can you try with `session.setHibernateFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);`

Comment: I have tried that. Please check my code.

Comment: May I know what is the issue with flush mode ? What is your expected outcome from the code. Flush option is managed by hibernate framework to synchronize the cache with database. It will be good if you are more precise with your question